# Markov inequality to compute upper bound probability

Tags: probability

Problem statement:

The mean weight of a kind of animal is 212gr. None of such a kind has a weight of less than 165gr. Find an upper bound for the probability of observing the weight of some of them being at least 250gr.

**Wrong Solution:**

```
P(X>=250) = P(X - 165 >= 85) <= (250-212)/85
```

I could say that the solution follows the Markov inequality. Still, questions remain on the logic that relates the subtractions.

--Edit--

**Correct Solution:**

From the good comments received I learned that the correct solution is:

```
P(X>=250) = P(X - 165 >= 85) <= (212-165)/85
```

but common sense still is not connecting the dots here for me so I try to find my way through basic algebra.

Which one of these is closer to the reasoning behind this solution?

1. *Scaling*:

start with the Markov inequality P(X>=a) <= E[x]/a, then scale down both X and E[x] by 165, while a=85.

2. *Expectations*:

knowing that E[x]=212 and that the two possible values for X are 165 and 250 then:

212 = E[x] = 250p + 165(1-p)

p = (212-165)/85

**Questions:**

- Which one is correct?
- Is the 165 the lowest mean mentioned in the comments statement: "Construct the distribution with the lowest possible mean that passes both tests"?
- Are there better interpretations?

Comment: This seems a bit off.  If we consider the binary case, where $X$ is either $250$ or $165$ and use this probability we get that the mean is $≥203$ which is not a contradiction.  Just playing with it, I get an upper bound of about $.56$ for this probability.  To say anything more would require more assumptions about the distribution.

Comment: Should say:  the simple reasoning I described leads to a precise upper bound of $\frac {212-165}{85}=0.552941176$  so perhaps this is what they intended to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the reasoning is "taking out the 165gr from the X on the left, and from the mean, on the right".

Comment: It's just commonsense.  Construct the distribution with the lowest possible mean that passes both tests.  In this case, if $p=P(X≥250)$ we have "$X=250$ with probability $p$ and $X=165$ with probability $1-p$".  Anything else will have higher mean.  So then we must have $250p+165(1-p)=212$ and the desired result follows.